# Detecting the presence of small details in an image

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I'd like to detect regions in an image which contain a comparatively large amount of small details, but equally I need to ignore strong edges. For example I would like to (approximately) identify regions of small text on a poster which is located on a building, but I also want to ignore the strong edges of the building itself.

I guess I'm probably looking for specific frequency bands, so approaches that spring to mind include: hand tuning a convolution kernel(s) until I hit what I need, use specific DCT coefficients, apply a histogram on directional filter responses. But perhaps I'm missing something more obvious?

To answer a question in the comments below, I'm developing in Matlab

I'm open to any suggestions for how to achieve this - thanks!

Comment: I'm no image processing expert, but this kind of sounds like one of those "I'll need five years and a research team" problems.

Comment: well that made me lol!

Comment: What platform are you developing for? Matlab has a lot of this functionality readily available. In fact, even if you weren't, developing in Matlab and then translating functions to your preferred language is the best choice. I will further edit my answer with a couple of more points, which might set you in the right direction.

Comment: Good point @sipty I've updated my question, yes I'm developing in Matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something unscientific, but maybe not bad to get folks talking. I start with this image.

[image]

and use the excellent, free `ImageMagick` to divide it up into tiles 400x400 pixels, like this:

```
convert -crop 400x400 cinema.jpg tile%d.jpg
```

Now I measure the entropy of each tile, and sort by increasing entropy:

```
for f in tile*.jpg; do
   convert $f -print '%[entropy] %f\n' null:
done | sort -n
```

and I get this outoput:

```
0.142574 tile0.jpg
0.316096 tile15.jpg
0.412495 tile9.jpg
0.482801 tile5.jpg
0.515268 tile4.jpg
0.534078 tile18.jpg
0.613911 tile12.jpg
0.629857 tile14.jpg
0.636475 tile11.jpg
0.689776 tile17.jpg
0.709307 tile10.jpg
0.710495 tile16.jpg
0.824499 tile6.jpg
0.826688 tile3.jpg
0.849991 tile8.jpg
0.851871 tile1.jpg
0.863232 tile13.jpg
0.917552 tile7.jpg
0.971176 tile2.jpg
```

So, if I look at the last 3 (i.e. those with the most entropy), I get:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Using entropy is an interesting idea - and could easily be able on any overlapping NxM block

Comment: It's pretty easy, and you can do it straight at the command-line without needing to compile anything. It is installed on many Linuxes and available for Windows and OS X too - ideally via `homebrew`.

Comment: Would this approach still be accurate for color images?

Comment: @Sipty Yes, I don't see why not. Have a try - it is installed on many Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

The question itself is too broad for a non-paper worthy answer on my side. That being said, I can offer you some advice of narrowing the question down.

First off, go to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/) and search for the keywords your work is revolved around. In your case, one of them would probably be *edge detection*.

Look through the most recent papers ( no more than 5 years ) for work that satisfies your needs. If you don't find anything, expand the search criteria or try different terms.

If you have something more specific, please edit your question and let me know.

Always remember to split the big question into smaller chunks and then split them into even smaller chunks, until you have a plate of delicious, manageable bites.

EDIT: From what I've gathered, you're interested in an edge detection and feature selection algorithm? Here are a couple of helpful links, which might prove useful:

[-MATLAB feature detection](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/feature-detection-extraction-and-matching.html)
[-MATLAB edge detection](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html)

Also this [MATLAB edge detection write up](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/edge-detection.html), which is a part of their *extensive* guide documentation will hopefully prove useful enough for you to dig through the [Matlab image processing toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html). documentation for specific answers to your question.

Comment: I think this is the most generic answer ever, and it certainly does not answer the question.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't directly answer the question, but it does seem like good advice regarding solving problems in general.

Comment: @amit And purposefully so. The only answer to OP's question is "Yes." and look at your nearest image processing manual. 

I am giving an answer which points OP in the right direction, as there really isn't any other *viable* answer to the current question.

Comment: In fairness, it is a very reasonable response to my pretty open ended question - so many thanks for taking the trouble to respond

Answer (score 1):

You'll find Maximally Stable Extremal Regions ([MSER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)) useful for this. You should be able to impose an area constraint to filter out large MSERs and then calculate a MSER density, for example as Mark had done in his answer by dividing the image into tiles.